# scanimage only recognizes scanner as ADF suddenly

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, brother, sane

I was using `scanimage` to scan some documents with my Brother DS-620 sheetfed scanner with the following command:

```
    scanimage --device 'dsseries:usb:0x04F9:0x60E0' \
      --format=tiff \
      --mode 'Gray' \
      --resolution 300 \
      -l 90 \
      -t 90 \
      --brightness -20 \
      --contrast 15 \
      > ex.tiff
```

I was testing different parameters for -t, which I think I set to 500, when mid way through scanning when the sheet feeder stopped and I believe a segfault error was thrown (sorry I lost the exact error message and cannot replicate it, although, `-t` has a maximum value of 355.6 in the device specific man page, which possibly explains a segfault). After that the above command and `scanimage -T` (for testing) both give the error `sane_start: Document feeder out of documents`. Below the device dependent option for `--source` says the only option is ADF, which I think is incorrect. The scanner was working perfectly before this happened. I have tried unplugging the scanner, rebooting my computer, and trying xsane, simple-scan etc with negative results. I've posted some of what I think is important information below.

Does anyone have any clues as to what went wrong and how to fix/troubleshoot this problem?

---

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.
scanimage and libsane versions:

```
desktop:~$ scanimage --version
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.23; backend version 1.0.23
```

The driver installed from Brother website:

```
libsane-dsseries_1.0.5-1_amd64.
```

The changelog for the driver:

```
x64-dsscanner (1.0.5-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * Fix duplex cut image error.

 -- Brother Industries, Ltd. <>  Thu, 21 Nov 2013 14:42:01 +0800
```

Device specific info:

```
desktop:~$ scanimage --help -d 'dsseries:usb:0x04F9:0x60E0'
Usage: scanimage [OPTION]...

Start image acquisition on a scanner device and write image data to
standard output.

Parameters are separated by a blank from single-character options (e.g.
-d epson) and by a "=" from multi-character options (e.g. --device-name=epson).
-d, --device-name=DEVICE   use a given scanner device (e.g. hp:/dev/scanner)
    --format=pnm|tiff      file format of output file
-i, --icc-profile=PROFILE  include this ICC profile into TIFF file
-L, --list-devices         show available scanner devices
-f, --formatted-device-list=FORMAT similar to -L, but the FORMAT of the output
                           can be specified: %d (device name), %v (vendor),
                           %m (model), %t (type), %i (index number), and
                           %n (newline)
-b, --batch[=FORMAT]       working in batch mode, FORMAT is `out%d.pnm' or
                           `out%d.tif' by default depending on --format
    --batch-start=#        page number to start naming files with
    --batch-count=#        how many pages to scan in batch mode
    --batch-increment=#    increase page number in filename by #
    --batch-double         increment page number by two, same as
                           --batch-increment=2
    --batch-prompt         ask for pressing a key before scanning a page
    --accept-md5-only      only accept authorization requests using md5
-p, --progress             print progress messages
-n, --dont-scan            only set options, don't actually scan
-T, --test                 test backend thoroughly
-A, --all-options          list all available backend options
-h, --help                 display this help message and exit
-v, --verbose              give even more status messages
-B, --buffer-size=#        change input buffer size (in kB, default 32)
-V, --version              print version information

Options specific to device `dsseries:usb:0x04F9:0x60E0':
  Scan mode:
    --mode LineArt|Gray|Color [Gray]
        Selects the scan mode (e.g., lineart, monochrome, or color).
    --resolution 75..600dpi (in steps of 1) [300]
        Sets the resolution of the scanned image.
    --preview[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Request a preview-quality scan.
    --source ADF [ADF]
        Selects the scan source (such as a document-feeder).
  Geometry:
    -l 0..215.9mm [0]
        Top-left x position of scan area.
    -t 0..355.6mm [0]
        Top-left y position of scan area.
    -x 0..215.9mm [215.9]
        Width of scan-area.
    -y 0..355.6mm [355.6]
        Height of scan-area.
  MultiFeed Detection:
    --ultrasonic Disable [Disable]
        Use ultrasonic sensor to detect multifeed
  Enhancement:
    --brightness -100..100% (in steps of 1) [0]
        Controls the brightness of the acquired image.
    --contrast -100..100% (in steps of 1) [0]
        Controls the contrast of the acquired image.
    --gamma-table 0..255,...
        Gamma-correction table.  In color mode this option equally affects the
        red, green, and blue channels simultaneously (i.e., it is an intensity
        gamma table).
    --red-gamma-table 0..255,...
        Gamma-correction table for the red band.
    --green-gamma-table 0..255,...
        Gamma-correction table for the green band.
    --blue-gamma-table 0..255,...
        Gamma-correction table for the blue band.

Type ``scanimage --help -d DEVICE'' to get list of all options for DEVICE.

List of available devices:
    dsseries:usb:0x04F9:0x60E0
```

Inconsistent behavior for detection of scanners:
Sometimes if I issue `sudo sane-find-scanner` I get that it doesn't find any usb scanner and that `sudo scanimage -L` lists my scanner. 
Previously and without any identifiable cause `sudo sane-find-scanner` just hangs and `sudo scanimage -L` gets me an Ubuntu system error and the report a problem dialog windows which I can't copy-paste but the important parts seem to be:

- ProblemType: Crash
- SegvAnalysis: Segfault happened at: 0x0: cannot access memory at address 0x0 PC (0x00000000) not located in a known VMA region (needed executable region)!
- SegvReason: executing NULL VMA
- Signal: 11

I'm at a loss with this erratic behavior.

Without `sudo`:

```
desktop:~$ scanimage -L
device `dsseries:usb:0x04F9:0x60E0' is a BROTHER DS-620 sheetfed scanner

desktop:~$ sane-find-scanner 

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x8087/0x8000 at 002:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x8008 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f9/0x60e0 at 003:005: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x046d/0xc016 at 003:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x046d/0xc315 at 003:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.

desktop:~$ sudo sane-find-scanner 

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Using `scanimage -n --device 'dsseries:usb:0x04F9:0x60E0' etc...` gives the correct message for a successful scan:

```
scanimage: rounded value of br-x from 305.9 to 215.9
scanimage: rounded value of br-y from 445.6 to 355.6
```

If I can test another scanner I will post results.

Comment: Try with another USB port, and avoid USB3.0. Some scanners are quite picky on that.

Comment: I tried this and did not help. I will try another computer at some point.